# Is there recomended/standard way to keep Grails domain classes instances persist with open-dolphins presentation models

Tags: grails, opendolphin

I'd like to make my usage of open-dolphin in grails sever as easy as possible. So, I'm looking for way to handle CRUD actions on domain classes(on the server side) automaticaly. In demos from open-dolphin project I havent found any idea how to achieve this(if I missed something, please point me where I should study). Instances are pulled from server on request and until it would be pulled/updated again there is no way to recognize changes that happen on server(I've been investigating mainly crudDemo in open-dolphin project).

Since CRUD actions can come not only from user via web or remote client, but also as consequence of other actions, cascade deletes, from services etc.(changes made to the database via sql, are probably untreatable), I thing that handle  actions in classes controllers is not enough.

I came up with idea of handling CRUD actions using [GORM events](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping), with those I can keep dolphin models persistent with database, check PMs before update or delete, and probably handle all changes on domain classes instances that grails is doing. But, I have to write very similar logic to each class, be sure I havent missed any event on any class(scaffolding may help) and there are probably other consequences that I do not realize now..

**So my question is:** Is there any documentation, pattern, plugin, open-source code, etc., where open-dolphin is implemented into grails that way, that it autamaticaly propagates CRUD actions on domain classes instances to its presentation models? Or anything that aims to achieve this, using scaffolding, observing instances lists and properties, or something else?

Maybe, I misunderstood concept of using open-dolphin with grails, if so, I appreciate any good advice.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

for some reason I haven't seen your question before.
You can happily use Grails domain classes and GORM with OpenDolphin on the server side. The "CrudDemo" in OpenDolphin does exactly that. 
Here are the domain classes: https://github.com/canoo/open-dolphin/tree/master/dolphin-grails/grails-app/domain/dolphin/grails
Here are the actions: https://github.com/canoo/open-dolphin/tree/master/subprojects/demo-javafx/server/src/main/groovy/org/opendolphin/demo/crud

Note that when we do testing and client and server-side actions run in-memory, there is no grails support available. Therefore, the server-side actions use service interfaces with DTOs instead of Grails domain classes. The implementation as a Grails service then uses Grails domain classes and GORM.

enjoy
Dierk